# Avg number of comparisons for failure in this sequential search algorithm?

Tags: performance, search, average

The algorithm:

```
public boolean search(int[] A, int target)
{
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        if(target==A[i]) return true;
        if(target<A[i]) return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this problem - I know it has something to do with the series, but the introduction of two comparisons per iteration really has me stumped. Can anybody help me out and explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

How I used to look at this was:

think of the best case, whats the least possible comparisons you can have? that would be when:

```
target==A[0] //first element
```

think of your worst case, whats the most comparisons you can have? that is when:

```
target==A[A.length-1] ///last elements or not found
```

so what would be our average case?

well take into consideration that first element is really fast, but last element is slow (O(1) vs O(n))
also as you move away from the begginning it starts taking longer, but at the same time as you get away from the end it gets faster. so your average case would lie in the middle.

if you are looking for a specific number avg number of comparisons might be

3 comparisons "for comparrison,target == A[i], target < A[i]   times n/2 " which is our *average* number of comparissons

if you want to test it you can make a counter and increase 1 everytime you do a comparison in your algorithm